# how do i remove a value from array session in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

My application is to collect customer and after choice customer and put some product in badge shopping .here everything is ok but when i  move to other customer ?
I want to delete the old product or how to notify user to pay and move to other customer and thank you advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use this two remove session 
$request->session()->forget('key');

$request->session()->flush();

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Comment: Thank you for your response have you any idea how full my shopping card juste buy product for one customer ' my application to collect all customer arround me using map here and you know when i use session i can keep product and move other customer and put other product

Comment: didn't get you please explain what do u want

Comment: My application is :collect customer any way let me say for exemple custom buy t shirt and other customer buy mobile phone i have two customer buy different product .here is my problem i add product t shirt in my shopping card and when i move to customet he buy mobile phone i can also add the product in shopping card me i dont want to add two different product to different customer

Comment: How can i do to avoid this ?

Comment: public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id){
            $product = Produit::find($id);
            $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
            $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
            $cart->add($product, $product->id);
            //dd($cart);
            $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
          // dd($request->session()->get('cart'));
            //$c=Commercant::findOrFail($id);

            return redirect()->route('front.show',compact('product'));
        }

Comment: i want to add the product for one customer ,if the user want to move to other customer and the have product in cart shopping i want to notify to buy it or to delete after moving ??